# How can I get rid of Bower and use gulp to manage front-end dependencies

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I moved all bower dependencies into package.json. The app is using gulp. Gulp can make a bundle file with all js code, but what about js code from node_modules which actually is used on the UI, like angular etc.
So the question actually is:
can I manage "front-end" libraries (which are now in node_modules) by using gulp. If it so, then how I can do this.

Comment: Yes. Or even just npm without gulp. http://george.webb.uno/posts/gulp-and-npm-for-front-end-web-development https://hackernoon.com/how-to-automate-all-the-things-with-gulp-b21a3fc96885 https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8 etc

Comment: I even didn't know that npm can do what gulp does. Thank you for the references!

Comment: For better or worse, there are about as many ways to package JavaScript as frameworks. You might want to consider npm vs. yarn, and separately webpack, gulp... For Angular there's even angular-cli.